# How do I htaccess redirect and rewrite index.php & parameters to new url, without changing links or files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

If I have a website with url of

```
/index.php?view=prod&id=11
```

(where 11 can be any id number)

How do I redirect **and** rewrite this to an SEF link like

```
/product/11/
```

So that anyone that goes to the index.php... link will always get redirected to the SEF link?

My solution so far is

```
RewriteRule    ^product/([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?view=prod&id=$1 [NC,L]
```

But that doesn't redirect the original index.php link at all, and though the SEF link works for some reason it doesn't display any CSS.... which is weird.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the `.htaccess`, use:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?view=prod&id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /product/%1/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^product/(\d+)/?$ index.php?view=prod&id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Change `[R=302]` for `[R=301]` when test work well.

Comment: I'm working in a sub-directory on a local server with XAMPP at the moment. Is there any reason why this would not work on this setup?

Comment: I don't know... Bad configuration for root/base directory. You can't use directory, and after try to rewrite from the root.

Comment: Still no effect unfortunately... even with removing `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Change also `RewriteRule ^ product/%1/? [R=302,L,NE]` without /

Comment: What exactly is the problem ? Error message ?